# Reactjs: What is the right way to modify a object in a large array in state?

Tags: reactjs

I have thousands of objects in an array stored in state, like this:

```
state: {
    data: [{name: 'a', status: true}, {name: 'b', status:false}, ...]
}

this.state.data.length > 10000
```

I want to modify some status in the array, like set `status` from `this.state.data[1000]` to `this.state.data[3000]` to `true`;

I used to clone the data into a new array first, but I met some performance issue for this. Since all we have clone are the object references, when we modify the cloned array, we are still modifying the actual object. So I don't know if it is still meaningful to clone the array.

And what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React got [an update helper](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) to deal with this kind of situations

```
import update from 'react-addons-update'


this.setState(
{
    data: update(this.state.data,{
                    [indexToChange] : {
                        status: {$set: true}
                    }
                })
}
```